# codeigniter pagination not wotking

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I spend so many time to resolve it, But the issue is the same, I need pagination in my application, I already loaded the pagination library, I dont able to understand what is the issue, Below is my code.

**Controller**

```
public function index($offset=0)
{

    $cnt=count($this->model->getDatamodel('item_cat_master'));
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'item/itemcat';
    $config['total_rows'] = $cnt;
    $config['per_page'] = 4; 
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $data['view'] = $this->model->get_my_data('item_cat_master', $config['per_page'], $offset);
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('menu');
    $this->load->view('item/item_cat', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');


}
```

**Model**

```
public function getDatamodel($table)
{
$query=$this->db->get($table);
return $query->result_array();
}

Public function get_my_data($table, $limit, $offset) 
{
$query = $this->db->get($table, $limit, $offset);
return $query->result_array();
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <!-- start:dynamic data table -->
                        <div class="adv-table">
                            <table  class="display table table-striped" id="example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><input id="checkAll" type="checkbox"></th>
                                        <th>Category Name</th>
                                        <th>Category Description</th>
                                        <th>Modidied On</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php foreach ($view as $key) { ?>                 
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ck[]" value="<?php echo $key["cat_id"]; ?>"></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $key["ic_name"]; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $key["ic_desc"]; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php $mo = $key["modifiedon"]; echo date("d-M-Y , H:i:s", strtotime($mo)); ?></td>
                                        <td>
                                        <?php
                                        $this->load->model('alldata','model'); 
                                        $encrypted_id = $this->model->encryptdata($key['cat_id']); 
                                        ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>item/itemcat/upditemcat/<?php echo $encrypted_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="" data-original-title="Update"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>    
                                        <!-- <a href="#" class="btn-success btn-xs" title="view"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a> --></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php } ?>    


                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end:dynamic data table -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                   echo $this->pagination->create_links();
                ?>
```

What is the Problem in my code? Can anybody guide me in right direction?

[image]

**in config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/riims';
```

**htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /riims/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<ifmodule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: So, What's The Problem? Pagination Not Displaying Or Pagination Not Working ?

Comment: Links are displaying but page not displaying, 404 page not found

Comment: update your question with routes

Comment: So, only URL Problem. Check Once, Whether desired URLs are present in Pagination Links. May be, URL not provided correctly.

Comment: So `item/itemcat` i.e `itemcat` function available in `item`controller?

Comment: Item is a folder, itemcat is a class and by default index is function

Comment: @NanaPartykar how to provide url correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main method is `index` which will call by default. But when you use pagination you have to add `index` in url or you have to configure `route` accordingly. Add `index` in pagination url then try

```
public function index($offset=0)
{

    $cnt=count($this->model->getDatamodel('item_cat_master'));
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'item/itemcat/index'; //add index at end
    $config['total_rows'] = $cnt;
    $config['per_page'] = 4; 
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $data['view'] = $this->model->get_my_data('item_cat_master', $config['per_page'], $offset);
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('menu');
    $this->load->view('item/item_cat', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');


}
```